# Can I concatenate multiple MySQL Column into One Column?

Tags: mysql

Good day i would like to ask if this is possible in MySQL

```
 SELECT id,label,name,age,sex FROM table LIMIT 3
```

**Output**

```
[row1] id,label,name,age,sex
[row2] id,label,name,age,sex
[row3] id,label,name,age,sex
```

**My Output Needed**

```
[row1] id
[row2] label
[row3] name
[row4] age
[row5] sex
[row6] id
[row7] label
[row8] name
[row9] age
[row10] sex
[row11] id
[row12] label
[row13] name
[row14] age
[row15] sex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT id AS id1, 1 AS rownum, 'id' AS colname, id AS Data_value FROM mytable LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, 2, 'label', label FROM mytable LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, 3, 'name', name FROM mytable LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, 4, 'age', age FROM mytable LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, 5, 'sex', sex FROM mytable LIMIT 3)) A 
 ORDER BY id1, rownum
```

Here's a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dvg6x1vBg6H5bDNp9VZxQa/4

I've added 3 additional column `id AS id1`, `rownum` and `colname`. The first two additional column is used for `ORDER BY` at the outer query. If you don't want to see the additional column, you can just type `SELECT Data_value FROM ...` at the outer query.

Comment: Thank This is exactly what i need

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_concat()` to aggregate rows by string concatenation. For the `LIMIT` to work you then need to use a derived table. But you should be careful with a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`. As the order of a query result can be random unless an explicit `ORDER BY` is issued, you may get different results each time you run the query.

```
SELECT group_concat(id,
                    '\n',
                    label,
                    '\n',
                    name,
                    '\n',
                    age,
                    '\n',
                    sex
                    SEPARATOR '\n')
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    label,
                    name,
                    age,
                    sex
                    FROM elbat
                    LIMIT 3) x;
```

---

If you just want to concatenate the columns but keep the rows just use `concat()`.

```
SELECT concat(id,
              '\n',
              label,
              '\n',
              name,
              '\n',
              age,
              '\n',
              sex)
       FROM elbat
       LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: it gives me result of 1 column and 1 row result. and not in multiple rows.

Comment: @RaynerPangan: It's not entirely clear what you expect. But check the edit, maybe that helps.

Comment: If you have the `SEPARATOR` as `\n`, why do you need to have `\n` listed between each item? You'll end up with two newlines between each item, won't you?

Comment: @ButtleButkus: The separator is put between expressions of **rows**.

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can use `union all` like below :

```sql
SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 3
union all
SELECT label FROM table LIMIT 3
union all
SELECT name FROM table LIMIT 3
union all
SELECT age FROM table LIMIT 3
union all
SELECT sex FROM table LIMIT 3
```

Comment: you beat me by 8 seconds :)

Comment: Wouldn't this give `id,id,id,label,label,label...`?

Comment: it worked but i need output to be in order and not in `id,id,id,label,label,label...`

Answer (score 0):

That what you looking is to **Unpivot** data. For more info about pivot and unpivot you can check here.

http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/dba1/dba110.html

Unfortunately there is no easy way to unpivot in mysql.

The below script will work for **MySQL 8.0**

```
set @rowNum :=0;
set @string :=( 
       select group_concat(id,',',label,',',name,',',age,',',sex separator ',')
       from (
         select id, label, name, age, sex from mytable limit 3
       ) x
);


 with recursive
    R1 as ( select @string as items),
    R2 as ( select 1 as n 
             union 
           select n + 1 from R2, R1
           where n <= length(items) - length(replace(items, ',', '')))
    select distinct @rowNum := @rowNum+1 as rowNum, substring_index(substring_index(items, ',', n), ',', -1) output from R2, R1;
```